# Chrome: Mark bookmarked links on webpage

Tags: chrome, bookmark

Is there any chrome extensions or maybe hacks that can show to user that link already bookmarked?

Answer (score 1):

Although, I am not sure about finding the duplicate bookmark on the fly but you can try [Fast Bookmark Scanner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fast-bookmark-scanner/gjcmklpilmpfhfjpebhnapnglcppdbic?hl=en) - which may solve the purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it for "on the fly" purposes ) But thank you! I think I'll always open links and will check if it bookmarked already